# How to pass a file to an android service with android:isolatedProcess

Tags: android

I am trying to generate a thumbnail image from a PDF file in an android service with isolatedProcess = true. The reason for that is that the file is from an untrusted source and could be dangerous. The Android PDF Renderer documentation also refers to that issue see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.

```
If the file is from an untrusted source it is recommended to run the renderer in a separate, isolated process with minimal permissions to limit the impact of security exploits.
```

But my problem how can I pass the document from my application to the isolated service. If I use an intent and pass the document as a byteArray I get an TransactionTooLargeException. And if i try to pass the URI of the file and open an inputStream with the contentResolver I get an exception that an isolated process cannot access the contentResolver.

*Update example with important code snippets*

**Android Manifest:**

```
    <application>
    ...
       <service
                android:name=".util.thumbnail.ThumbnailCreationService"
                android:isolatedProcess="true"
                android:exported="false"
                android:process=":remote" />
    </application>
```

**Activity send Data to Service via Message Handler**:

```
    class MainActivity : Activity {  
    ...
     /**
         * Class for interacting with the main interface of the service.
         */
        private val mConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
            override fun onServiceConnected(
                className: ComponentName,
                service: IBinder
            ) {
                mService = Messenger(service)
                registerClient(mMessenger)
            }
    
            override fun onServiceDisconnected(className: ComponentName) {
                mService = null
                unregisterClient(mMessenger)
                // As part of the sample, tell the user what happened.
                Timber.d("Service disconnected")
            }
        }
    
    fun sendMessageToService(fileUri:Uri{
       mService?.let {
            val msg = Message.obtain(
                null,
                MSG_CREATE_THUMBNAIL, this.hashCode(), 0
            )
            val bundle = Bundle()
            // sending document URI to service 
            bundle.putString(ARG_DOCUMENT_DATA_URI, fileUri.toString())
            // or the document data which leads to a TransactionToLargeException
            // bundle.putByteArray(ARG_DOCUMENT_DATA, document)
            bundle.putString(ARG_DOCUMENT_MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
            msg.data = bundle
            it.send(msg)
        }
    }
```

**Service:**
ThumbnailCreationService

```
    class ThumbnailCreationService : Service() {
    
        var mClients = ArrayList<Messenger>()
    
        /**
         * Handler of incoming messages from clients.
         */
        internal class IncomingHandler(private val thumbnailCreationService: ThumbnailCreationService) : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                Timber.d("Retrieved client message: ${msg.what}")
                when (msg.what) {
                    MSG_CREATE_THUMBNAIL -> {
                        msg.data?.let {
                            val uri = Uri.parse(it.getString(ARG_DOCUMENT_DATA_URI))
                            thumbnailCreationService.loadDocumentData(uri)
                        }
                    }
                    else -> super.handleMessage(msg)
                }
            }
        }
    
        protected fun loadDocumentData(uri: Uri) =
    // this .contentResolver crashes because an isolatedProcess service has no access to the content resolver
            this.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use {
                IOHandler.readFileUriContent(it)
            } 
    }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Isolated process not allowed to call getContentProvider
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
                                                                                                        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5224)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:7019)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:3420)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2526)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:2011)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1842)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1518)
```

Comment: You might want to consider supplying an [mcve] for that last bit (`Uri` approach) along with the complete stack trace.

Comment: I have added the important code snippets and the stacktrace